# sitefinity two widgets on a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I have two widgets on a page one is loading the details of the page using the index action method passing in a id. The other widget is downloading a file to the user using the FileResult and passing in the fileId. Both pages are conflicting with each other is there something I am missing? The file is being open using a `ahref`.

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id)

public FileResult GetFile(string fileId)
```

Comment: what do you mean that they are conflicting with each other - what exactly is happening?

Comment: The page open using the id and then when you click href it will not open the file

Comment: I don’t want the information to be removed from the page